# (react-window) How to wrap {Row} with <div> or any custom component?

Tags: reactjs, row, material-ui, wrapper, react-window

I am using library called [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window)

It's library for efficiently rendering large lists and tabular data.

this is example code from the docs:

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window';

const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
  <div style={style}>Row {index}</div>
);

const Example = () => (
  <List
    height={150}
    itemCount={1000}
    itemSize={35}
    width={300}
  >
    {Row}
  </List>
);
```

What I want to do is wrap the {Row} with `<div>` or any other custom components.

Because I want to implement some styling and also collapse transition.

Note that, I cannot simply do this:

```
const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
   <div style={{...}}> // wrapper
      <div style={style}>Row {index}</div>
   </div>
);
```

Because it will wrap every single **list-item** with wrapper component, instead of wrap a whole lists with single wrapper component.

> I want to wrap a whole lists with single wrapper component.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a specific example of what you are trying to do.   Perhaps share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) demonstrating the look/functionality you want using a few rows of hard-coded data without using react-window.

Comment: It's pretty obvious what he wants, if you read.  I think the burden for asking a question is becoming tiresome.  He wants to wrap a whole list in a single wrapper element which he can style, e.g. classes and ids.

Comment: Did someone find a solution?

Comment: Why can't it go on the outside of the List component?